# How can I easily get a substring in Go while guarding against "slice bounds out of range" error?

Tags: go

Using Go, I want to truncate long strings to an arbitrary length (e.g. for logging).

```
const maxLen = 100

func main() {
    myString := "This string might be longer, so we'll keep all except the first 100 bytes."

    fmt.Println(myString[:10])      // Prints the first 10 bytes
    fmt.Println(myString[:maxLen])  // panic: runtime error: slice bounds out of range
}
```

For now, I can solve it with an extra variable and `if` statement, but that seems very long-winded:

```
const maxLen = 100

func main() {
    myString := "This string might be longer, so we'll keep all except the first 100 bytes."

    limit := len(myString)
    if limit > maxLen {
        limit = maxLen
    }

    fmt.Println(myString[:limit]) // Prints the first 100 bytes, or the whole string if shorter
}
```

Is there a shorter/cleaner way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a simple function to hide the implementation details. For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func maxString(s string, max int) string {
    if len(s) > max {
        r := 0
        for i := range s {
            r++
            if r > max {
                return s[:i]
            }
        }
    }
    return s
}

func main() {
    s := "日本語"
    fmt.Println(s)
    fmt.Println(maxString(s, 2))
}
```

Output:

```
日本語
日本
```

Comment: This does not handle multi-byte unicode characters. Try `s := "日本語"`.

Comment: @FilipHaglund: Fixed.

Comment: Nice, i was thinking of using range, but didn't think of obly using the index to avoid copying the string.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I guess `if len(s) > max` is an optimisation (see https://play.golang.org/p/P0fM6PNQYN) but worth keeping. It still seems like a lot of work in Go, but I've found the [xstrings library](https://github.com/huandu/xstrings) so will give that a try if I need this kind of thing often.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want to keep at most `maxLen` characters, i.e. what your code says, rather than what your string says.

If you don't need the original myString, you can overwrite it like this:

```
const maxLen = 100

func main() {
    myString := "This string might be longer, so we'll keep the first 100 bytes."

    if len(myString) >= maxLen {
        myString = myString[:maxLen] // slicing is a constant time operation in go
    }

    fmt.Println(myString) // Prints the first 100 bytes, or the whole string if shorter
}
```

This might cut unicode characters in half, leaving some garbage at the end. If you need to handle multi-byte unicode, which you probably do, try this:

```
func main() {
    myString := "日本語"

    mid := maxLen
    for len(myString) >= mid && utf8.ValidString(myString[:mid]) == false {
        mid++ // add another byte from myString until we have a whole multi-byte character
    }
    if len(myString) > mid {
        myString = myString[:mid]
    }

    fmt.Println(myString) // Prints the first 100 bytes, or the whole string if shorter
}
```

Or, if you can accept removing up to one character from the output, this version is a bit cleaner

```
func main() {
    myString := "日本語"

    for len(myString) >= maxLen || utf8.ValidString(myString) == false {
        myString = myString[:len(myString)-1] // remove a byte
    }

    fmt.Println(myString) // Prints the first 100 bytes, or the whole string if shorter
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't thought of unicode issues TBH. This is also a good solution, in case the original string isn't needed.